# Convert a png file to an array of hex values

Tags: java, image, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a program to display images in Java turtle. My idea is to convert an image into an array of color values, which my code will cycle through and display each pixel. I figured out how to display each pixel, but I am stuck on how I would go about converting an image file to an array of color values. I tried converting it to hex and then to color values, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: [`BufferedImage#getRGB`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,int)) will return a "packed `int`" representing the color value of the specified pixel. If you need an instance of `Color`, you can use [`Color(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Color.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)) or [`Color(int, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Color.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,boolean)) if you need to support alpha based palettes

Comment: There are different formats of image file, many of which involve compression. If you are going to process a .png file, you would either need to understand the format, or use another program to convert it to a format you do understand.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your attempt.